# MySQL select and join

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables Customers and CDR_Customers(these are just an examples of the fields):

```
mysql> select i_customer,i_parent from Customers where i_parent = 234 limit 1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
i_customer: 266
i_parent: 234

mysql> select i_customer, charged_amount, i_service from CDR_Customers where i_service=4 limit 1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
    i_customer: 64
charged_amount: 35.00000
     i_service: 4
```

What I want to achieve is to make a query which selects total "charged amount" from all "Customers" which has the same i_parent and i_service from CDR_Customers table = 4;

I've tried to write this query, but it does not seem correct:

```
mysql> select sum(a.charged_amount), b.i_parent from CDR_Customers a join Customers b on a.i_customer=b.i_customer where b.i_parent=234 and i_service = 4;
+-----------------------+----------+
| sum(a.charged_amount) | i_parent |
+-----------------------+----------+
|                  NULL |     NULL |
+-----------------------+----------+
```

Could you please advice?

Comment: `a.i_customer = 266 <> b.i_customer = 64 ` and aggregate function will always return at leat one row

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Your statement is correct. The result is null because the field i_customer value is 266 on Customers table and 64 on CDR_Customers. The JOIN clause will return the values only when these values are equals.